# Vert.x chunked answer with data from database using BLOB and hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, vert.x

I try to send in chunks binary data in response from database (Postgresql 9.6.5) using Hibernate 5.2.11.Final (BLOB type) and Vert.x 3.4.2, but I receive wrong response (it looks for me like some bits are missing). Here is my code in Kotlin:

```
fun getFile(user: User, messageId: Long, fileId: Short, response: HttpServerResponse) {
    val mediaContent = mediaContentRepository.getFile(messageId, fileId)
    when {
        mediaContent == null ->
            response.apply { statusCode = 404 }.end()
        conversationUserRepository.authorize(user.id!!, mediaContent.message!!.conversation!!.id, mediaContent.message!!.created) ->
            response.setChunked(true)
                    .putHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${mediaContent.name}\"") //TODO: prevent injections
                    .putHeader("Content-Type", mediaContent.contentType)
                    //.putHeader("Content-Length", mediaContent.file.length().toString())
                    .apply {
                        //write(Buffer.buffer().apply { delegate.setBytes(0, mediaContent.file.binaryStream.readAllBytes()) })
                        val buffer = Buffer.buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        val stream = mediaContent.file.binaryStream
                        val byteArray = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        for (i in (0L..(mediaContent.file.length() / BUFFER_SIZE))) {
                            val bytesRead = stream.read(byteArray)
                            buffer.delegate.setBytes(0, byteArray, 0, bytesRead)
                            write(if (bytesRead == BUFFER_SIZE) buffer else buffer.slice(0, bytesRead))
                        }
                    }
                    .end()
        else ->
            response.apply { statusCode = 403 }.end()
    }
}
```

But when I try to send whole file at once using this line, response is correct.

```
write(Buffer.buffer().apply { delegate.setBytes(0, mediaContent.file.binaryStream.readAllBytes()) })
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: It also can be helpful that I usually receive different responses for that same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working but I don't know exactly why it's working. It just for me looks like there is problem with reusing vert.x buffer in loops. Code below

```
fun getFile(user: User, messageId: Long, fileId: Short, response: HttpServerResponse) {
        val mediaContent = mediaContentRepository.getFile(messageId, fileId)
        when {
            mediaContent == null ->
                response.apply { statusCode = 404 }.end()
            conversationUserRepository.authorize(user.id!!, mediaContent.message!!.conversation!!.id, mediaContent.message!!.created) ->
                response.putHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${mediaContent.name}\"") //TODO: prevent injections
                        .putHeader("Content-Type", mediaContent.contentType)
                        .putHeader("Content-Length", mediaContent.file.length().toString())
                        .apply {
                            val stream = mediaContent.file.binaryStream
                            val byteArray = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)
                            for (i in (0L..(mediaContent.file.length() / BUFFER_SIZE))) {
                                val bytesRead = stream.read(byteArray)
                                write(Buffer(io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer.buffer(byteArray)
                                        .let {
                                            if (bytesRead == BUFFER_SIZE) it
                                            else it.slice(0, bytesRead)
                                        }))
                            }
                        }
                        .end()
            else ->
                response.apply { statusCode = 403 }.end()
        }
    }
```